# How rate of absorption remains same throughout the process?

Tags: physical-chemistry, adsorption, absorption

While reading surface chemistry, I got

> Rate of adsorption is high at begining and then decreases till equilibrium is attained . On the other hand , rate of absorption remains same throughout the process .

Regarding adsorption I have no doubts as logically after some time there will be no surface area  for upcoming molecules.
But how the rate can be same in case of absorption ?
Just if we  take an example of cotton ball , it absorbs water and after some time being fully wet by water how further the rate of absorbing be same ?
Please help if I am lacking somewhere in the concept ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your presumption is reasonable, but not complete. The text states, "remains same throughout the process." In your example, when the cotton ball is fully saturated, *the process ceases*, so the text appears to be correct. You've described the endpoint, where equilibrium has been reached, *after* the process ends.

However, you might test absorption to see if it behaves according to that general rule:

- Obtain some agar gel, phenolphthalein indicator, dilute $\ce{HCl}$ and dilute $\ce{NaOH}$ solution.
- Dissolve the agar in warm water, mixed with a little phenolphthalein indicator and a *drop* of $\ce{HCl}$, and pour into a vertical test-tube, leaving a few cm empty at top. Wait for the gel to cool to room temperature.
- Add a few ml of $\ce{NaOH}$ solution at the top.
- Every minute (or every ten minutes, if this is slow), mark the lower limit of the pink color.

Does the absorption, *and diffusion*, proceed uniformly, or does it slow with time?